# Meta description/keywords not being found by analyzer but do exist in source code?

Tags: php, html, seo, silverstripe, metatag

If I run our website ([www.deversus.com](http://www.deversus.com)) through a meta analyzer, such as the one at http://www.seocentro.com/tools/search-engines/metatag-analyzer.html our meta description/keywords are not found, but they do exist in the source code. Our website is using SilverStripe - I've checked a few other websites that use SS (even silverstripe.com) and the same problem exists. Has anyone seen this problem before, and if so, do you know what the cause of it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by removing http-equiv="keywords" and http-equiv="description" from the tags.